# Integrate Azure Dashboard in custom web applications

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, azure-dashboard

All my applications are using `Application Insights` to log their activities. I have created some queries to monitor what each application is doing or the status of them.

For personal use, I created some dashboard where I display graphs and data.

Now, I want to share this dashboard with some users. The idea is to integrate this dashboard in the company portal; so users can see the dashboard without leaving our environment or open a new tab in the browser. All my applications are build in `C#`. I don't want to use PowerBi.

How can I implement a dashboard in my application? What kind of configuration is it possible to have? Is there any documentation for that?

Answer (score 1):

1) You'd have to use the [Application Insights REST API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart) to read data directly and write your tool to display the data (or use other existing dashboarding things that already know how to use the REST API)

or

2) add your users as "reader" users to your subscription and share your dashboards with them in the azure portal

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using the first solution but I don't want to create my dashboard, my idea was to integrate (iframe?) an `Azure Dashboard` or at least add a link in my menu. The second idea: the user has to login in the `Azure Portal` and then it is useless to use my UI.

Comment: I saw `Workbook` in the `Azure Portal`: I can have a link for each workbook. The problem is the link doesn't work most of the time...

Comment: what do you mean the link doesn't work most of the time?  can you give me an example?